# Does anyone know the official rules for Destruct 3?

Tags: destruct-3

We've got our hands on an old Destruct 3 game that came without any rules.  We contacted the makers (Uncle Skunkle), but oddly enough, they wouldn't send us the rules without documentation of where we got the game. We've made up some rules of our own, but they're not entirely satisfying.  Anyone know the real rules, or where we can get them without any paperwork?

Comment: Looks like a pretty cool game!  I'd love to hear how it works, if you do find out.

Comment: why do they care where you got it from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://therealmajorfun.blogspot.com/2007/05/destruct-3.html) might help. Although it's only a review, it does explain a lot about the scoring and building rules. There obviously are a few rules that are missing (ie. how the dice work).

I assume you do not have any kind of shop receipt for the game. You could suggest to them that you could send them a picture of the game to prove you actually have it. They could describe a specific setup for you to replicate so you can't just pick a picture off the web.

Comment: Thanks!  We gave them the serial number on the game and they sent us the rules.  It's pretty much what we'd guessed, but the scoring is more complicated.  But the kids love getting the chance to destroy things, so I think we'll be playing it for awhile!